# Power BI - Real-time Streaming Data with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, real-time, dashboard

I would like to know how can I stream data from SQL Server to create real-time dashboards in Power BI?

(If a row is inserted in DB it updates automatically the dashboard).

Can anyone advise?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look into Server Sent Events  https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I think this wont help me

Comment: Are you aware of direct query in power bi?

Comment: Realistically, what is real time? 1 second latency? 10 seconds? 10 minutes? The only way I'm aware of to do this is have your database trigger invoke a REST API and push the data to Power BI. But I'm sure there's a better way. Have you read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-real-time-streaming Pick an API and start investigating it

Comment: Also, realisticallly, you shouldn't use triggers to push data like this because if they fail, your data ingestion fails, and you don't want that. Instead, your trigger should push them to a queue table, and an external process should pull them off and post them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45289442/how-to-call-restful-service-from-sql-server-trigger